# Wieso kann man das Zustandspassive mit Verben wie "bewundern", "loben", usw. nicht bilden?

Tags: verb-usage, passive

Im PDF-Dokument [C Grammatik](https://kupdf.net/download/c-grammatik_59108dfcdc0d60e62e959e82_pdf) von Anne Buscha, Szilvia Szita und  Susanne Raven, erschienen 2013 im Schubert Verlag, steht auf Seite 59:

> Das Zustandspassiv kann nur mit Verben gebildet werden, die ein Vorgangspassiv bilden können und die einen Vorgang beschreiben, aus dem überhaupt ein Zustand entstehen kann, z. B. *öffnen, schließen, schreiben* usw. Verben wie z. B. *bewundern, loben, betrachten, sehen, befragen, beglückwünschen, zeigen* können **kein Zustands­passiv bilden.**

Ich sehe einen Unterschied zwischen den Verben der ersten Gruppe und den der zweiten, d.h., die von der ersten sind "physikalischer", aber ich glaube nicht, dass das der in diesem Kontext wichtigster Unterschied ist.  Was ist die Nuance, die ich nicht sehe?

Ich gebe zu, dass

> Dieses Bild ist gezeigt.

seltsam wirkt, aber "unmöglich" scheint es mir nicht. Ist es, dass "gezeigt" kein Zustand ist?

Comment: Ich bin nicht ganz einverstanden mit dem, was Schubert hier schreibt: In vielen Texten findet man Formulierungen wie z.B. "betrachten wir die in Abb. xyz gezeigte Konstruktion", in Gerichtsprotokollen findet man "der Zeuge, nach den Vorgängen befragt, konnte keine Antwort geben",..... Da sehe ich kein Vorgangspassiv.

Comment: @tofro der Zustandspassiv setzt voraus, dass eine Form vom Verb "sein" anwesend ist, z.B. "Die Konstruktion ist gezeigt" oder "Der Zeuge ist befragt".

Comment: Du hast in der Überschrift versehentlich "öffnen" in die falsche Gruppe getan.

Comment: @CarstenS Nein, so ist es im Buch.  Ich habe nur "beglückwünschen", das im Buch war, von der zweiten Gruppe weggelasssen.  Sonst ist es, wie es da steht.

Comment: In der Überschrift deiner Frage hast du "loben" und "öffnen" nebeneinander, obwohl sie im Text in verschiedenen Gruppen sind.

Comment: @CarstenS Ich glaube, dass ein Punkt fehlte.  Das habe ich korrigiert.   Wenn es immer noch inkorrect ist, sag mir bitte Bescheid.

Comment: @Cerulean Die Aussage in der Überschrift widerspricht immer noch dem, was in der Frage steht. In der Überschrift steht, dass kein Zustandspassiv von *öffnen* gebildet werden kann. In der Frage steht (korrekterweise) das Gegenteil.

Comment: Der zitierte Text ist etwas der zu lesen, da, zumindest wie ich das lese, der Punkt nach "usw" in Doppelfunktion auch einen Satz beendet.

Comment: @RHA  Ah, die Überschrift!  Ich glaube, jemand hat das schon korrigiert.  Verzeihung...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. "Das Zustandspassiv kann nur mit Verben gebildet werden, die ein Vorgangspassiv bilden können" -- stimmt nicht. Allerdings wird manchmal der Trick verwendet, dass man bestimmte Gegenbeispiele einfach nicht Zustandspassiv nennt, nämlich in Fällen reflexiver Verben wie "ich erhole mich - ich bin erholt" (manchmal stattdessen "Zustandsreflexiv" genannt). Ferner gibt es ein Zustandspassiv von unakkusativischen Verben ( https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unakkusativisches_Verb ), das Problem ist nur dass man es vom Perfekt (hier mit dem Hilfsverb "sein") schwer unterscheiden kann. Eine Konstruktion wie "Der Finger ist immer noch angeschwollen" von dem nicht passivierbaren Verb "anschwellen" kann schätzungsweise kein Perfekt sein, weil das Perfekt kaum mit dem durativen Averb "noch" verträglich ist. Hingegen kann "Der Finger ist gestern angeschwollen" nur ein Perfekt sein (im Sinne: "die Veränderung ist gestern geschehen"). Der dritte Einwand betrifft Psychoverben wie etwa "das deprimiert ihn" - "er war davon sehr deprimiert", aber nicht "er wurde davon deprimiert".
2. "Nur Vorgangsverben, deren Vorgang zu einem Resultat führt, können ein Zustandspassiv bilden" -- stimmt nicht. Außer man nennt diese Beispiele dann wiederum anders. Hier gibt es zwei Typen: (a) Vorgangsverben, die kein Resultat bezeichnen; diese können eine Konstruktion bilden, die bedeutet: Man ist fertig damit, eine Aufgabe ist erfüllt. Beispiel: "die Hymne ist gesungen (das Spiel kann beginnen)". Das geht meistens, braucht aber starke Stützung aus dem Kontext. (b) Vereinzelt gibt es Beispiele mit Zustandsverben, oder zumindest durativen Verben, wo es dann gar nicht um einen Nachzustand geht, sondern eigentlich um denselben Zustand, nur mit neuem Subjekt. Sogar das oben genannte "zeigen" liefert Gegenbeispiele (kann man googeln): "Wie das funktioniert, ist in der nächsten Abbildung gezeigt" klingt tadellos. Auch: "Das Haus ist bewohnt", "er ist schwer bewacht", "der Wagen war von zwei Pferden gezogen". Ich weiß aber nicht, wie man voraussagen kann, mit welchen derartigen Verben es geht; mit vielen tatsächlich nicht, da hat die Frage nicht ganz unrecht.

Comment: Danke!  Also ist das Buch nicht zu vertrauen?  Oder ist es vielleicht nur so, dass sie alles etwas einfacher machen wollten, um Lernende nicht zu verwirren?  Man hat mir das Buch empfohlen. 

Comment: Das was da genannt war, habe ich auch in anderen Quellen schon gelesen. Der eine schreibts vom anderen ab, gerade mit dem Ziel, vertrauenswürdig zu sein :) Ungenauigkeit spielt auch eine Rolle, vielleicht wollen sie eigentlich sagen, bei welchen Verben man sich zunächst drauf verlassen kann, dass es ein ZP gibt. Das Buch ist vielleicht nicht schlechter als andere... Ich hab deswegen so ausführlich reagiert, gerade weil ich derlei schon oft gelesen hab.

Comment: Absätze machen, kennste? TL;DR

Comment: "*"[…] ist in der nächsten Abbildung gezeigt" klingt tadellos.*" Bedaure mitzuteilen, nein. Außerdem klingt 2 Pferde Stärken nur bemotleodenswert ("der Wagen war von zwei Pferden gezogen"). *Gezogen* hat doch ofensichtlich irgendein Bezuch zu griechisch *zygon* "Jochen".

Answer (score 2):

Die Nuance ist genau das, was in der Beschreibung steht: Der Vorgang muss zu einem Zustand führen, in den das Subjekt des Passivsatzes ohne den Vorgang nicht gelangt wäre.

Beispiel 1:

Eine Tür ist zu zuerst im geschlossenen Zustand.

- Vorgangspassiv:

  > Die Tür wird geöffnet.

  Dieser Satz beschreibt einen Vorgang, der eine Zustandsänderung bewirkt. Weil er einen Vorgang beschriebt, spricht man von einem Vorgangspassiv.
- Zustandspassiv:

  > Die Tür ist geöffnet.

  Dieser Satz beschreibt einen Zustand, der die Folge eines Vorgangs ist. Wenn niemand die Tür geöffnet hätte, wäre sie jetzt nicht geöffnet. Weil der Satz einen Zustand beschriebt, spricht man von einem Zustandspassiv.

Wenn man aber die Tür nicht öffnet, sondern nur betrachtet, ist das Betrachten zwar auch ein Vorgang, der mit einem Vorgangspassiv beschrieben werden kann, aber das Betrachten verändert den Zustand der Tür nicht.

Beispiel 2:

Eine Tür ist zu zuerst geschlossen, aus Holz, weiß lackiert und hat ein paar Kratzer.

- Vorgangspassiv:

  > Die Tür wird betrachtet.

  Dieser Satz beschreibt einen Vorgang, der keine Zustandsänderung bewirkt. Weil er einen Vorgang beschriebt, spricht man von einem Vorgangspassiv.
- Zustandspassiv:

  > Die Tür ist betrachtet.

  Dieser Satz ergibt keinen Sinn. Die Tür ist nach wie vor geschlossen, aus Holz, weiß lackiert und hat ein paar Kratzer. Sie befindet sich also auch nach der Betrachtung in genau demselben Zustand wie davor. Wenn niemand die Tür betrachtet hätte, wäre sie in genau demselben Zustand wie nach der Betrachtung. Daher ergibt es keinen Sinn, das Verb *»betrachten«* im Zustandspassiv zu verwenden, auch wenn sich die grammatischen Regeln (*»ist«* statt *»wird«*) leicht anwenden lassen. Nicht jeder grammatisch korrekt gebaute Satz ist sinnvoll.