# Nochmal zur Verbreitung des Selbst-Reflexiven Pronomens

Tags: grammar-identification, grammaticality, dialect

Ich stelle eine alte Frage zur [Verbreitung des Selbstreflexiven Pronomens](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/56162/verbreitung-des-selbst-reflexiven-pronomens) erneut, da das Thema nicht richtig beschrieben wurde. Die Antwort war für's erste auch sehr hilfreich, immerhin nicht falsch, trifft jedoch den Kern der Frage nicht, den ich hier noch einmal verdeutlichen will.

> Stimmt es, dass in südlichen Dialekten die Verwendung des Pronomens *sich* nach einigen Verben, die im Hochdeutsch bzw. in meinem Idiolekt nicht selbst-reflexiv sind, zumindest in festen Wendungen üblich ist?

Was daran missverständlich war, erschließt sich mir nicht.

Z.B. heißt es *Der Laden hat geöffnet*, oder etwa *ist auf*. Eine reflexive Konstruktion wäre denkbar, meiner Meinung nach jedoch unüblich: "Der Laden hat sich geöffnet". Dieses Beispiel ist aus der Luft gegriffen, mag irreführend sein, ist mir auch egal.

Belastbare Beispiele vergleichbarer Analogien werden mit fuffzig Internetpunkten fraglicher Herkunft entlohnt.

Stein des Anstoßes ist diesmal übrigens eine Frage zum [Zustandspassiv](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/75486/wieso-kann-man-das-zustandspassive-mit-verben-wie-bewundern-loben-usw-nic) bzw. *Zustandsreflexiv*.

Comment: Bitte definiere *»selbst-reflexiv«*. Ist damit etwas anderes als *»reflexiv«* gemeint, oder doch dasselbe? Ich unterscheide diese drei Kategorien: **1. transitiv** *»Sie wäscht das Auto.«* **2. unecht reflexiv** (auch *»pseudoreflexiv«*) *»Sie wäscht sich.«* und **3. echt reflexiv** *»Sie schämt sich.«* Meinst du mit *»selbst-reflexiv«* eine dieser drei Kategorien, oder meinst du etwas anderes? Falls du eine dieser drei Kategorien meinst, bitte ich dich den Ausdruck *»selbst-reflexiv«* durch den gängigen Begriff zu ersetzen. Wenn du etwas anderes meinst, bitte ich um eine klare Definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Die Frage bezog sich auf *»die südlichen Dialekte«,* womit vermutlich die hochdeutschen und besonders die oberdeutschen Dialekte gemeint sind, die sich wiederum in die alemannischen Dialekte und die bairischen Dialekte unterteilen lassen. (Alemannisch: deutsche Dialekte der Schweiz, Liechtensteins, Vorarlbergs, großer Teile Baden-Württembergs, des Westens Bayerns (Schwaben), des Piemont in Italien und des Elsass in Frankreich. Bairisch: deutsche Dialekte in Altbayern, Österreich ohne Vorarlberg und Südtirol in Italien)

Ich kann leider nur Aussagen über einen Teil der bairischen Dialekte machen, nämlich über die mittelbairischen Dialekte. Es gibt nämlich auch die nordbarischen Dialekte (größte Verbreitung in der Oberpfalz und in Teilen von Ober- und Mittelfranken) und die südbairischen Dialekte (im Wesentlichen die Dialekte der österreichischen Bundesländer Tirol und Kärnten), die sich in einigen Merkmalen von den mittelbairischen Dialekten unterscheiden, und mir ist leider nicht klar, ob das, was ich hier ausführe, auch für nord- und südbairische Dialekte gilt.

Mittelbairische Dialekte haben starken Einfluss darauf, was im österreichischen Standarddeutsch als korrekt gilt, und vieles, was ich hier aufliste, ist tatsächlich korrektes österreichisches Standarddeutsch, allerdings glaube ich auch, dass einige der hier als *»mittelbairisch«* angeführten Varianten auch im deutschen Standarddeutsch zumindest als erlaubte Varianten geduldet werden.

| Mittelbairisch | deutsches Standarddeutsch |
| --- | --- |
| Ich erwarte **mir** ein wertvolles Geschenk. | Ich erwarte ein wertvolles Geschenk. |
| Es lohnt **sich** nicht, darauf zu warten. | Es lohnt nicht, darauf zu warten. |
| Es steht **sich** nicht dafür, dass du dich so abrackerst. | Es steht nicht dafür, dass du dich so abrackerst. |
| Klaus kniete **sich** nieder. | Klaus kniete nieder. |
| Die Hose zwickt **mich** an den Oberschenkeln. | Die Hose zwickt an den Oberschenkeln. |

Eine Besonderheit des Wiener Arbeiterdialekts, der vor allem in den südlichen und östlichen Bezirken Wiens, aber auch in daran angrenzenden Gemeinden Niederösterreichs gesprochen wird, ist der doppelte Reflexiv:

| Wiener Arbeiterdialekt | sonst |
| --- | --- |
| Schwarzkappler zum Fahrgast ohne Fahrschein: »Können Sie sich **Ihnen** ausweisen?« | Kontrolleur zum Fahrgast ohne Fahrschein: »Können Sie sich ausweisen?« |

Comment: Die Beispiele mit "lohnen", "knien", "zwicken" erscheinen mir absolut nicht spezifisch bairisch, sondern komplett akzeptables (vielleicht seltenes, zumindestens die beiden letzteren) Hochdeutsch.

Comment: @tofro: Ich habe mir eher erwartet, dass *»**sich** etwas erwarten«* auch in der Nordhälfte Deutschlands gängig sei.

Comment: Erstens ist das letzte kein "Arbeiterdialekt", sondern einfach Resultat Wiener Dialekts. Im Wiener Dialekt ist nämlich "sich"="ihna" und das "Sie" wird zu "'S" verkürzt: "Kennan'S Ihna..."="Können Sie sich.." Da das "Ihna" so ähnlich wie "Ihnen" klingt, wird, wenn der Dialektsprecher Hochdeutsch versucht, das Wiener Doppel-Reflexivum daraus, weil das "Ihnen" natürlich nicht das (durchaus gefühlte) Bedürfnis nach einem "sich" stillt und deshalb ein zusätzliches "sich" eingefügt wird. Zweitens ist der "Fahrgast ohne Fahrschein" in Wien ein "Schwarzfahrer".

Comment: @bakunin Ich denke, "eahna" == "sich" ist eher zweifelhaft. Zumindestens im Bayrischen bairisch sagt man "die is eahna nachglaffa", was deutlich nicht "sich" heißt.

Comment: @tofro: da das "Ihna" (was sicher die wienerische Variante von "Eahna" ist) aber regelmäßig an genau der Stelle auftaucht, wo im Hochdeutschen ein reflexives "sich" steht, liegt der Verdacht aber schon nahe, daß es sich um das entsprechende Wort handelt, oder? Bsp: "Schaumen'S Ihna" (Schämen sie sich), "Kennan'S Ihna vurstön" (Können sie sich vorstellen), etc.. Ja, "Ihna" kann *auch* "Ihnen" (Akkusativ oder Dativ von "sie" ) sein ("Kennt Ihna so passn"=Könnte Ihnen so passen; "De haum Ihna bedacklt"=die haben Sie betrogen), aber das ist wohl Homonymie.

Comment: @bakunin Ich würde eher argumentieren, dass das bairische gar keine Reflexivpronomen kennt und stattdessen einfach die Formen von "Sie" und "Du" und "Er",... verwendet.

Comment: Davon ganz abgesehen: In einem Kommentar zur Frage wird eine Definition, was "selbst-reflexiv" überhaupt ist, eingefordert - durchaus zu Recht, wie ich meine. Dann aber - als derjenige, der selbst von sich sagt, nicht zu wissen, was das überhaupt sein soll - eine Antwort zu produzieren, halte ich für grenzwertig. "Ich weiß zwar nicht, was die Frage ist, aber ich habe eine (sinnvolle!) Antwort darauf"??

Comment: @tofro: nein, das ist eben nicht der Fall. Das "Sie" wird zu "'S" verkürzt, wie der Vergleich von Höflichkeits- zu Normalform zeigt: "Kennan**'s** Ihna ..."="Können *Sie* sich ..." aber "Kauns**'d** di ..."="Kannst *Du* dich ..."

Comment: @bakunin Man kann auch auf eine Frage, die man nicht versteht (oder: die so formuliert ist, dass sie nicht verstehbar ist...) versuchen, zu antworten. Vielleicht hilft's dem Frager ja weiter. Mit demselben Grund hättest du auch auf deinen ersten Kommentar zur Antwort verzichten müssen....

Comment: @tofro: Wieso? Ich muß ja nicht die Frage verstehen um zu erkennen, daß die Antwort (in sich) nicht schlüssig ist. Wenn jemand "x+1=x" als Lösung angibt, dann muß ich auch nicht die Frage kennen, um zu erkennen, daß das nicht richtig sein kann, weil das für keinerlei x stimmt.

Comment: @bakunin: In Wien, wie auch in allen anderen größeren Städten, gibt es in unterschiedlichen Gesellschaftsschichten unterschiedliche Dialekte. Die High Society, die in der Wiener Innenstadt, aber auch in den nordwestlichen Stadtrandbezirken (Hernals, Währing, Döbling) lebt, spricht einen ganz anderen Dialekt als die Arbeiter aus Favoriten und Simmering. Der doppelte Reflexiv gehört nur zu den Dialekten der letztgenannten Bevölkerungsgruppe.

Comment: @tofro: Bairische Dialekte haben sehr wohl Reflexivpronomen: *»Warum **sih** der Hansl nit niedergsetzt hot.«* (Titel eines Buches, das [mein Großvater geschrieben hat.](https://www.zvab.com/buch-suchen/autor/sch%F6lnast/)) Das Wort *»sih«* in diesem Titel ist die oststeirische Variante von *»sich«.* Außerdem: *»I hob **mi** gschreckt, du host **di** gfreit, wir hom **uns** griaßt.«* aber in der 2. Person Höflichkeitsform eben nicht *»Sie hom **sih** gfreit.«* sondern *»Sie hom **eahna** gfreit.«* (Ich habe mich erschreckt, du hast dich gefreut, wir haben uns gegrüßt. Sie haben sich gefreut.)

Comment: Nochmal: das "Doppel-Reflexivum" ist *keinerlei* Dialekt, sondern das Resultat des Versuchs, aus dem Dialekt in die - ungewohnte - Hochsprache zu wechseln. "Arbeiterdialekt" ist das also nur dann, wenn man unterstellt, daß Arbeiter=ungebildet und der Hochsprache nicht mächtig, Nobelbezirk=gewählte Hochsprache bedeutet.

Comment: @bakunin: Der Begriff *»Arbeiterdialekt«* war keineswegs abwertend gemeint. Und wenn ich im Geiste einige Vertreter der Wiener [Seitenblickegesellschaft](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seitenblickegesellschaft) durchgehe, stelle ich fest, dass deine Behauptung, diese Leute wären gebildeter als die Arbeiter, nicht in allen Fällen haltbar ist.

Comment: Wo habe ich das "behauptet"? Etwa dadurch, es eine "Unterstellung" (und zwar eine hypothetische: "wenn man unterstellt...") genannt zu haben?

Comment: Ich finde die Antwort akzeptabel. Das dritte Beispiel ist (mir) leider nicht verständlich. Zu viertens sehe ich den Unterschied ähnlich wie *hinlegen*, *liegen*, *hing, hang*. Ob *sich knien* echt reflexiv ist, nur weil eine starke Beugung (ha!) zu *knechten* nicht erkennbar ist und *Knicks machen* als lautmalerisch gilt, sei dahingestellt.

Comment: Übrigens, da *Können S' sia ihn ...* meinetwegen als \*könnens mit hochdeutscher Lautverschiebung und Adsimilation als *z* zu lesen sein kann, könnte das auch eine reine Flektionsform sein (zufällig hört man in Berlin seit kurzem "Es gibt's", auch *Arbeiterklasse*, z.B. Oberschullehrer).

Comment: Zwicken ist doch pseudo-reflexiv. Das passt nicht in die Liste